# Why does various functions on sublime text 3 disappeared suddenly?

Tags: sublimetext3

I was coding on sublime text 3 and I wanted to copy and paste a section of my code somewhere else.
So I did ctrl + arrow keys. But it didn't copy and paste like usual. It only moved the thing. So I tried again, but in vain. Also, I wanted to make a doc string. So I typed double quote two times and then moved the cursor in between the quotes to wright. But when I began to wright, it replaced the last double quote with my text. I tried again and it had the same result. I tried reinstalling it, but it didn't work. I searched on stack overflow and they didn't have my question. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you press Insert on the keyboard accidentally and go into overwrite mode? If so, just press it again to revert.

Comment: Where is the insert button?

Comment: Oh I found it, No I don't think so, the insert button is on the other side of the keyboard

Comment: Oh, your right, my mad :P thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Since it seems correct, I've posted it as an answer; upvoting and accepting would be appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally pressed the Insert key or otherwise got your system into overwrite mode, instead of the standard insert mode. By pressing Insert again, this is reverted, and things will be back to working as normal.